# New event doesn't have latest state value updated by previous event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, lexical-scope

Here is the situation,

```
const MyComp = () => {
    const timelineOverlayRef = useRef(null);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

    const mouseDownHandler = e => {
        setPosition({ x: 0, y: 100});
    };

    const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
        console.log(position);
    }

    const init = () => {
        timelineOverlayRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);

        timelineOverlayRef.current.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);

    }

    useEffect(init, []);

    return <div ref={timelineOverlayRef}>My Div where I want to capture mouse down and mouse move events</div>;
}
```

When I click on my div and start moving the mouse I don't see the updated position where y equals 100. instead I have the initial state value with y = 0. Any idea on why this might happen and how to overcome this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure mouseDownHandler and mouseMoveHandler  were called?

Comment: Yes, I did console log just after enterring the event handler. And they were logging fine.

Comment: mousemove is executed before that mousedown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onMouseMove` and `onMouseDown` events on div.

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const timelineOverlayRef = useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const mouseDownHandler = e => {
    setPosition({ x: 0, y: 100 });
  };

  const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
    console.log(position);
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={timelineOverlayRef}
      onMouseMove={mouseMoveHandler}
      onMouseDown={mouseDownHandler}
    >
      My Div where I want to capture mouse down and mouse move events
    </div>
  );
};
```

Your code is not working because new instances of event handler functions are being created each time component re-renders and event listener has old reference of the function which was created after component was mounted.

Add the event handler functions as dependencies of `useEffect` and remove the events in clean-up function.

The following code should work fine.

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const timelineOverlayRef = useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const mouseDownHandler = e => {
    console.log("clicked...");
    setPosition({ x: 0, y: 100 });
  };

  const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
    console.log(position);
  };

  const init = () => {
    timelineOverlayRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
    timelineOverlayRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler);

    return () => {
      timelineOverlayRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "mousemove",
        mouseMoveHandler
      );
      timelineOverlayRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "mousedown",
        mouseDownHandler
      );
    };
  };

  useEffect(init, [mouseDownHandler, mouseMoveHandler]);

  return (
    <div ref={timelineOverlayRef}>
      My Div where I want to capture mouse down and mouse move events
    </div>
  );
};
```

To make above code simpler, you can use this custom hook: https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/

Comment: Now the events handlers are not called.

Comment: Here is the working code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w4atrn

Comment: In stackblitz demo it works fine. But locally doesn't work. Thanks for your effort. But what I really want to know is why my given code doesn't work.  A solution would be nice. But my main concern is understanding why it doesn't work. Thanks. BTW I can make it work if I declare positions as function varible instead of state.

Comment: The useEventListener link was helpful. Thanks.